# Internet by rj11. one router - two pcs

Tags: internet, router

I´m wondering if is possible to get Internet conection from one router to two pcs. (There is not network between the two pcs). The conection available is through rj11.
Thank you.

Comment: RJ-11 is a formfactor of a PLUG, it has nothing to do with the wiring, pinout, or signaling happening between two machines. Is this “router” really a “modem”?  You need to clarify your question, otherwise you will get a bunch of answers that may end up frying whatever components you try to piece together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small switch this would do the job. SImply connect the switch to the router using a RJ11 - RJ45 cable. Then using RJ45 (Ethernet) cable connect the 2 pc's to the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Most routers have more than one ethernet port, so you can connect more than one PC, no need for a switch, what model of router do you have? Or do you mean modem?

Answer (score 1):

There are phone line network adapters, and power line network adapters, but they are relatively expensive.  The better option, assuming the computers are reasonably close together (in the same house) is to create a wireless network.  Wireless USB adapters can be had for ~$20 currently.

Comment: I agree with you, but I have two diferents OS, one pc has w2000 and the other has wxp. And I have problems to install a bluetooth driver in w2000

Comment: Bluetooth?  By wireless I meant 802.11 wifi.  Of course w2000 is still an issue, but older 802.11b era adapters should support it.